# Android Kotlin function with multiple optional parameters, call function only with parameters at specific place

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have this function that has 8 optional parameters (yes I know it's bad practice to have that much, this is legacy code :D).

It goes something like this:

```
private fun function(
    rightImage: Int = 0,
    background: Int = R.drawable.account_item_bg,
    leftImage: Int = 0,
    translation: String? = null,
    name: String? = null,
    age: String? = null,
    length: String? = null,
    duration: String? = null)
```

Now in my code, I want to call this function and give it only the last parameter (duration). I don't care for other ones.

But at the moment to call this, I Would do it like this:

```
function(0, R.drawable.account_item_bg, 0, null, null, null, null, 1800)
```

I was just thinking in the moment of writing this code that it would be cool to have option to send only parameters at the particular place (f.e parameter 6, or last parameter), and not repeat all the optional ones.

Is there maybe option like this, does anyone know? Thanks

Comment: `function(duration = 1800)` should have worked. What error are you getting?

Comment: yes it works now, answer is updated. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments

Example code:

```kotlin
function(duration = "1800")
```

Comment: This does not work, try it in code. It throws error and asks me to add the first parameter also

Comment: I've just update my example code. So please verify it. @Kratos

Comment: Yes it works now. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by specifying the argument name.

e.g. `function(1, 1, duration = "")`

You don't necessarily have to do it for every argument but if you skip some then yes

Comment: yes I want to do skipping. With this option if I want to send f.e only last parameter, this does not help me. I still have to write all of them before coming to the last one

Comment: @Kratos Ehm, either you don't or I don't know what you mean. The (1,1... was just an illustration that it's either order or if you don't follow the order, you have to use naming.

Comment: okay now I got you. I wrongly interpreted it at first. Thank you, I gave you upvote :D